# Which interface ensure read a fixed number of bytes unless EOF is reached?

Tags: go

According to the doc of `io.Reader`, it says.

```
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}

...

Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered.
```

It is not quite clear what `n` mean here. Does it mean the number of bytes to read unless EOF is reached? Or it just means an upper bound or the number of bytes to read even when EOF is not reached?

Could anybody clarify what it is? Thanks.

Comment: `n` refers to the first return value. It is the number of bytes read. Read can return a positive vale for `n` And a non-nil error. Use Io.ReadFull to fill the buffer.

Comment: Is there a way in go to ensure to read n bytes unless EOF is reached?

Comment: Yes. Make the buffer `n` in length. Typically in Go, when performing operations like `io.Copy`, implicit buffers are created - 32K in size. Read operations will read this many bytes at a time & similarly for writes. The io.Reader interface leverages these buffers to avoid the overhead of reading from the datasource for each individual byte directly. So during a large copy, `n` will be 32K for every read, except for the final read - when io.EOF is encountered - then `n` will be <= 32K.

Answer (score 3):

The contract is that `Read` will read at most `len(p)` bytes into the buffer.

If it can read all `len(p)` bytes, then `n=len(p)`.

If it reads less (either because end-of-file is reached, or because underlying implementation returned only the buffered data), then `n` will be less. It can be 0.

`Read` is one of those functions that return a meaningful result even if err!=nil. If read stopped because it hit end-of-file, it may return number of bytes read and io.EOF.